# Getting wrong Access Token from PowerBI api endpoint

Tags: azure, authentication, access-token, powerbi, adal

I have a strange situation related to PowerBI endpoint

```
https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
```

I have two users:

1. client-1-1@somedomain.com
2. client-9230-10609@somedomain.com

I use following piece of code to get AccessToken:

```
    public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(PowerBiUser powerBiUser)
    {
        try
        {
            var username = powerBiUser.GetUserPrincipalName(AppSettingsRepository.PowerBiTenantName);
            var password = powerBiUser.GetPassword();
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}");
            var userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
            var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api", ClientId, userCredential);

            return token.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The second user has been removed from Active Directory and there is a problem that I am getting identical JWT access token for each user.

It looks like getting access tokens for PowerBI users doesn't work properly for me. Does anybody meet with this kind of situation? Is that any well known bug or something? Everything worked fine when user existed in Active Directory ({tenant-id}), but after removing the user it stopped working.

Comment: This looks like an authentication question, not a Power BI question. Please reach out to the ADAL folks.  Double check if there's caching happening somewhere in your stack.

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for your suggestions. I don't catch any exception in that case. I just get incorrect access token for user which does not exist. It looks like some AD issue.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure why you'd be getting that. If it's still happening I'd suggest calling the support line since there's something clearly not working correctly.